# How do I use a C++ API in Android?

Tags: android

I was recently looking for some way to embed an Adobe PDF file reader in my Android apps and someone on SO suggested Adobe Reader Mobile 9 SDK.

On their FAQ they say their SDK consists of a set of C++ API's.     How do I go about accessing an API written in C++ in an Android app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use JNI, probably to and from a native wrapper you would write to interact with the API on its terms.  But the important questions are if that code is available in a form compatible with android's runtime environment (usually meaning built with the NDK toolchain) and if you can get your output in a usable form.

Comment: fwiw, if you can't get a android version of the Adobe SDK, I do know that the mupdf library works with android via JNI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if someone has converted the library to one that is accessible in your Android environment. Maybe someone has already converted to version you can use from Android but often not the case.

If not, you will need to see if you can run the source (you will need the source), through NDK cross compiler to obtain a version of the library that can be loaded in an Android app.

So follow the steps here, post if you run into issues: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html